# How to ignore Mule IMAP connector failure on start-up

Tags: java, mule, imap

I added IMAP connector to my Mule instance, for some email message processing. During Mule start up, if connector is not able to connect to IMAP, it throws exception and prevent Mule app from starting up. Is there any way prevent this for happening? For example, if connector fails, it should try to reconnect maybe in separate thread, but the rest of the app should be able to function, or the error should be ignored, and the rest of the flows should be initialised.

I tried to add reconnect strategy, but it didn't work.

```
<imaps:connector name="imaps" mailboxFolder="${email.ingestion.mailboxFolder}" deleteReadMessages="${email.ingestion.deleteReadMessages}">
    <reconnect frequency="3000" blocking="false" />
    <imaps:tls-client path="*" storePassword="*"/>
    <imaps:tls-trust-store path="*" storePassword="*"/>
</imaps:connector>
```

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

A non blocking reconnection strategy is the way to go. If it doesn't work, please [report an issue](http://mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE).